# Using Truffle with Node JS (MongoDB)

Tags: truffle, javascript, nodejs, aws

I am trying to use truffle along with a MongoDB database which means that I need multiple ports.

For local testing, I have been starting up my RPC, switching the port that the app is listening, and then running nodemon to launch my server for MongoDB. However, this means I have to visit two separate web pages with one running the Ethereum Blockchain side of things and the other only running the MongoDB side.

How can I use both Mongo and Truffle when deploying with AWS?